# openRewrite: Unable to configure org.openrewrite.java.spring.framework.UpgradeSpringFrameworkDependencies

Tags: openrewrite

Getting below warning error while running UpgradeSpringBoot_3_0 recipe through maven command line.

```
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:dryRun   -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-spring:RELEASE   -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_0
```

Warning error log

```
[WARNING] Unable to configure org.openrewrite.java.spring.framework.UpgradeSpringFrameworkDependencies
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "this.newVersion" is null
    at org.openrewrite.java.spring.framework.UpgradeSpringFrameworkDependencies.getRecipeList (UpgradeSpringFrameworkDependencies.java:84)
    at org.openrewrite.Recipe.createRecipeDescriptor (Recipe.java:152)
    at org.openrewrite.Recipe.getDescriptor (Recipe.java:144)
    at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.configureRecipes (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:166)
    at org.openrewrite.config.ClasspathScanningLoader.scanClasses (ClasspathScanningLoader.java:135)
....................
....................
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug! Should be fixed in v5.0.6 release coming up shortly. You can watch this page for progress: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/releases

Comment: What could be the impact in current release due this error warning, will UpgradeSpringBoot_3_1 work even with this warning? should we ignore this warning for now?

Comment: I think the message was mostly harmless, but I still recommend an upgrade to 5.0.6+ , which is now available.